# HTML data attributes and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so I'm building a portfolio plugin for WordPress. Users will be able to insert a shortcode into their content and display a portfolio.

Each Portfolio will use jQuery Isotope, with custom settings for each one.

I want to be able to display multiple portfolios on one page, and have their respective Isotope jQuery arguments initialized.

So I went about adding data attributes with the settings to each portfolio container, with a common class on each of them.

Then I set up a JS file with the following (simplified):

```
var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-listing');
var $eachContainer = jQuery('#' + $container.data('portfolio-id'));

$eachContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $eachContainer.isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.portfolio-item.item-' + $eachContainer.data('portfolio-id'),
        layoutMode : $eachContainer.data('layout'),
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML (simplified):

```
<div id="test" class="portfolio-listing" data-layout="masonry" data-portfolio-id="test">
    <div class="portfolio-item item-test">
         ... inner portfolio stuff
    </div>
</div>

<div id="another" class="portfolio-listing" data-layout="fitRows" data-portfolio-id="another">
    <div class="portfolio-item item-another">
         ... inner portfolio stuff
    </div>
</div>

<div id="onemore" class="portfolio-listing" data-layout="masonry" data-portfolio-id="onemore">
    <div class="portfolio-item item-onemore">
         ... inner portfolio stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the first portfolio on the page getting the correct arguments, and then the rest of them just mimicking the first portfolio's arguments.

Anyone have any ideas for me?

Comment: Can we get some more code? It's a little confusing what's being repeated here. Add multiple blocks of the result html etc., so we can see the repetition.

Comment: For sure - adding a couple more blocks of the code. So basically, I want the JS to talk to each individual container's data attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS

```
var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-listing');
var $eachContainer = jQuery('#' + $container.data('portfolio-id'));

$eachContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $eachContainer.isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.portfolio-item.item-' + $eachContainer.data('portfolio-id'),
        layoutMode : $eachContainer.data('layout'),
    });
});
```

Will only select the first portfolio div into `$eachContainer` if you want the operation to be carried out on all the divs you will have to iterate over the object set `$container`

change your JS to

```
var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-listing');
$container.each(function () {
    var $eachContainer = jQuery('#' + $(this).data('portfolio-id'));

    $eachContainer.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $eachContainer.isotope({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.portfolio-item.item-' + $eachContainer.data('portfolio-id'),
            layoutMode: $eachContainer.data('layout'),
        });
    });
});
```

This way `$eachContainer` will be each of the `.portfolio-listing` divs rather than just the first one

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!